# Cannot update ListView using ObservableCollection methods via a derived class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are two views, the first view contains a ListView along with 2 buttons for adding and removing a person. View 2 shows the selected view by using a ContentControl, when the Add button is clicked it shows a form with the name, gender, …, and a button to store the information and display the person name in the ListView. 
When I try to remove a person from the ListView it works since the button is within the same view/context of the ListView. But when I call the Add method via AddViewModel it does not update the UI.
Below it is available the relevant parts code of the different classes.

[View sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUjkn.png)

**View1.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="addViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:AddViewModel}">
        <views:AddView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

    <Button Command="{Binding change2addViewCommand,
                            Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Plus" Width="12"/>
     </Button>
     <Button Command="{Binding removeFromListCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvNames, Path=SelectedItem}">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Delete" Width="12"/>
                </Button>
      <ListView MinHeight="560"
                          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                          x:Name="lvNames" >
      </ListView>
      <ContentControl x:Name="controllerViews" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    Grid.RowSpan="5" Content="{Binding CurrentView, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
public class ViewModelBase: ObservableCollection<Person>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ViewModelBase currentView;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return currentView;
        }
        set
        {
            currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public ViewModelBase()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            Add(new Person()
            {
                Name = "Person" + i,
                Age = i,
                Gender = Gender.Female,
                Comments = "",
                Photo_Path = ""
            });
        }
        change2addViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteAddCommand, CanExectuteAddCommand);
        removeFromListCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteRemoveCommand, CanExectuteRemoveCommand);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool CanExectuteAddCommand(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteAddCommand(object param)
    {
        CurrentView = new AddViewModel();
    }

    public bool CanExectuteRemoveCommand(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteRemoveCommand(object param)
    {
        Person player = param as Person;
        Remove(player); //Working

    }

    protected void AddToListView(Person player)
    {
         Add(player) // Not Working

    }

}
```

}

**AddViewModel.cs**

```
public class AddViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand addViewCheckCommand { get; set; }
    public AddViewModel()
    {
        addViewCheckCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteCheckCommand, CanExecuteCheckCommand);
    }

    private bool CanExecuteCheckCommand(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteCheckCommand(object param)
    {
        BocciaPlayer player = param as Person;
        AddToListView(player); // Inherited method
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked using the debugger that the AddToListView() method actually gets hit when you click the button?

Comment: You don't seem to be setting a DataContext anywhere, e.g. the one of the MainWindow. Instead you're explicitly specifying the source of your Bindings as `Source={StaticResource ViewModel}`. So how is `Content="{Binding CurrentView}` supposed to work? Btw, setting `Mode=TwoWay` is pointless there.

Comment: @Baldrick Yes. I have checked and it hits when I click the button. The Add method is not updating the ListView, I think it is because the context is different but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I tried removing the pieces of code that did not work, and I can tell you that the Add method seems to work. So, the problem must be in the Context. Try putting breakpoints in the constructor to see if there are more instances created of the same class, and see if the correct instance is called when you press the button.

Comment: @LupuSilviu When I click the add button the ViewModelBase class constructor is called again. Thereby creating a new instance of this class.

Comment: If you upload your code to some repository I'd try to check it because it seems like you have misunderstood the way MVVM should be applied. ViewModelBase shouldn't have a property of ViewModelBase it makes no sense. Btw, you could use "Snoop" to see if any of your bindings are wrong

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez Only very recently I have been working with MVVM so I appreciate any feedback. The link of the project is: https://gitlab.com/Drovok/MultipleViewsMVVM

Comment: @JamesDrovok5 I didn't forget about you but it's kinda hard to understand + rewrite it. I will mention you when I finish ;)